# extract values from a data frame based on a vector of row numbers in R

Tags: database, r, vector

I am trying to extract a vector of values from a data frame based on a vector of row numbers;

```
df<-iris
x<-c(1,5,15,8,7,2)
```

I want the corresponding Species of the row numbers listed in the vector x. I have tried something like `df$Species[x,]` and `df$Species[list(x),]` to no avail. I am sure the answer is something really simple but I just can't see it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just `df$Species[x]`. `df$Species` is a 1-dimensional vector, so to index it, you just need a single set of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df[x,]$Species
```

or

```
df[,"Species"][x]
```

or indeed

```
df[x,"Species"]
```

Comment: All those options and you missed the low hanging fruit of `df$Species[x]`?